# How to deploy angularjs app in production without port

Tags: angularjs, deployment, production

I'm having an application built with AngularJS (not Angular 2) and is ready to get deployed. In Angular 2+, we'll be building the project and the output of that build command will be a set of html, js, css files with assets folder. I can keep them in my webroot(htdocs in case of Apache server) and run the application. But how to do the same in AngularJS app?

Please note that I don't want to use npm start which actually runs on a port. I've an Apache server and I wanted to place my code in that folder (say htdocs/myAngularJSApp) and I want to access it using www.mydomain.com/myAngularJSApp.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no need to build. Just host it and it will work.